# How to convert LocalDateTime back to Instant without knowing timezone but with Clock?

Tags: java, datetime, date-arithmetic

I can [create `LocalDateTime` with `Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-). After having some manipulations, like adding units of time, I would like to convert it to `Instant`. But it requires timezone. How to get it?

```
Clock clock = Clock.fixed(...);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
localDateTime = localDateTime.plusMinutes(60);
return localDateTime.toInstant(clock.getZone().getRules().getOffeset(...I need instant I don't have yet!...)
```

Comment: Can't you use the localDateTime as the parameter for getOffset()?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a zone offset e.g. `ZoneOffset.UTC` to [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-). Alternatively, you can create a `ZonedDateTime` using [`LocalDateTime#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and convert the same to an `Instant`.

```
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
        localDateTime = localDateTime.plusMinutes(60);

        // UTC
        Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // A custom zone offset
        instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Your JVM's default timezone
        instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        // A specific timezone
        instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Ceuta")).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-10T14:30:35.294134Z
2021-03-10T12:30:35.294134Z
2021-03-10T14:30:35.294134Z
2021-03-10T13:30:35.294134Z
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you still have access to the `Clock` at the time when you want to convert back to `Instant`. You can trivially get the time zone from the clock. Then the conversion goes like this:

```
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.EPOCH, ZoneId.of("Pacific/Tahiti"));
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
    localDateTime = localDateTime.plusMinutes(60);
    Instant convertedBack = localDateTime.atZone(clock.getZone()).toInstant();
    
    System.out.println(convertedBack);
```

Output from this sample snippet is:

> 1970-01-01T01:00:00Z